# Getting the gradients of a model trained in OpenNMT-py

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, machine-translation, opennmt

When training a model using OpenNMT-py, we get a dict as output, containing the weights and biases of the network. However, these tensors have requires_grad = False, and so, do not have a gradient. For example. with one layer, we might have the following tensors, denoting embeddings as well as weights and biases in the encoder and decoder. None of them have a gradient attribute.

encoder.embeddings.emb_luts.0.weight

decoder.embeddings.emb_luts.0.weight

encoder.rnn.weight_ih_l0

encoder.rnn.weight_hh_l0

encoder.rnn.bias_ih_l0

encoder.rnn.bias_hh_l0

decoder.rnn.layers.0.weight_ih

decoder.rnn.layers.0.weight_hh

decoder.rnn.layers.0.bias_ih

decoder.rnn.layers.0.bias_hh

Can OpenNMT-py be made to set requires_gradient = True with some option I have not found or is there some other way to obtain the gradient of these tensors?

Comment: Gradients with respect to what? The gradients are only defined with respect to a particular training batch, so they are discarded after training. Moreover, during training, the gradients get zeroed after each step.

Comment: With respect to each training batch, yes. I guess that this information is not retained then. Do you have experience with OpenNMT-py and where in that code, for example I would add a tensorboardX writer to track things like the gradient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradients are accessible only inside the training loop, where `optim.step()` is called. If you want to log the gradients (or norm of gradients or whatever) to TensorBoard, you can probably best get them before the optimizer step is called. It happens in the [`_gradient_accumulation`](https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py/blob/master/onmt/trainer.py#L330) method of the `Trainer` object.

Be aware that there are two places where `optim.step()` is called. Which one is used depends on whether you do the update after every batch or whether you accumulate gradient from multiple batches and do the update afterward.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am sorry for bothering further, but would you happen to know where to look for the hidden states in the RNN in the code?